# Spring Boot Application RestController defined outside Application can not be accessed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to use both java and Spring Boot for the first time, following a tutorial.

I have created a class called UserController in a package called User, in which I have defined an endpoint, contents of UserController.java :

```
package com.example.demo.user;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> hello() {
        User myUser = new User(5000, 1, 1);
        return List.of(myUser);
    }
}
```

User package also includes class named User in User.java with getters, setters and constructers for the User class.

And in the same hierarchy as the user package, I have DemoApplication.java with the following content:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to receive a response such as [User] ......, however I get 404 not found.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiu4R.png) is what my project structure looks like

What am I doing wrong here? Searched a lot to find an answer to no avail.

Thank you for your help in advance.

When I modify the code so that I define the end point inside DemoApplication.java as such:

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.user.User;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/user")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> hello() {
        User myUser = new User(5000, 1, 1);
        return List.of(myUser);
    }
}
```

The endpoint starts working as expected.
But I was expecting it to keep on giving 404 because I am not doing anything fundamentally different.

This is the endpoint I'm sending GET requests using postman:
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. It might be your IDE playing tricks on you. What happens if you run the application from the command line (eg. by running `.\mvnw spring-boot:run`)?

Comment: @g00glen00b same result

Comment: you can try @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo"}) on top of your main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was because I was using special characters in the project directory. My windows is in Turkish and desktop is Masaüstü, in Turkish.

After enabling debug logs I found out that when the component scan was being conducted, it was throwing the following error:-

```
2023-02-24T16:19:22.500+03:00 DEBUG 4796 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Failed to complete search in directory [C:\Users\ARDA\OneDrive\Masa%c3%bcst%c3%bc\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo] for files matching pattern [*/.class]: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\ARDA\OneDrive\Masa%c3%bcst%c3%bc\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo
```

So I changed my project folder to somewhere else (and also had to remove the whitespace from the folder name) and the problem was solved.

Comment: You are running into [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34379).